# How do I suppress asp:image AlternateText from html escaping?

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp:Image -- which I'm assigning "alt" and "tooltip" from the code behind. Unfortunately the value which is coming from the database is getting automatically html escaped -- which I do now want it to -- how do I suppress this?

For example my trademark html entity is doing this -->

```
&#174; gets changed to --> &amp;#174
```

-- which is incorrect

Here's my code in the aspx:

```
<asp:Image runat="server" ID="MainImage"  Width="260" />
```

Do I have any options?

Thanks,

-R

And here's my code behind:

```
this.MainImage.AlternateText = this.BasePage.SellGroup.DisplayName;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must say that this problem looked simpler than it is. From what I can tell, there is no means to override the Image's default behavior of Html encoding the alt tag. That leaves you with a couple of choices:

**Use HttpDecode**

Decode your data before you assign the AlternateText attribute. This is probably the simplest and techically since the Image control is encoding the `alt` attribute, this should work fine. It means that the actual registered symbol will render in the browser instead of `&#174;`

```
this.MainImage.AlternateText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode( this.BasePage.SellGroup.DisplayName );
```

**Use a Literal control**

Create a `Literal` control and set the attribute that way:

```
this.Literal1.Mode = LiteralMode.PassThrough;
this.Literal1.Text = string.Format( "<img src=\"{0}\" alt=\"{1}\" />", "Foo.jpg", "&#174;" );
```